# Assign to Readonly Property

Tags: c#, serialization

Hello i want to serialize an object but,
if try to deseriliaze a IEnumerable<> i get this error

Error   75  Property or indexer 'Nodes' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

My example code:

Serializing Part.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(sv.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
bin.Serialize(fs, graphControl.Nodes);
fs.Close();
```

Deserializing Part:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(op.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();

//Error Here

graphControl.Nodes = (IEnumerable<Node>)bin.Deserialize(fs);
```

Node Class Part:

```
public List<Node> graphNodes = new List<Node>();
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public IEnumerable<Node> Nodes { get { return graphNodes; } }
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

graphNodes shouldn't be public, but since it is, use it:

```
graphControl.graphNodes = (IEnumerable<Node>)bin.Deserialize(fs);
```

But it really shouldn't be public, so this is better:

```
graphControl.Nodes.Clear();
graphControl.Nodes.AddRange( (IEnumerable<Node>)bin.Deserialize(fs) );
```

...and make `graphNodes` private.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an `IEnumerable<Node>` you likely need to do it one item at a time:

```
graphControl.Nodes.Clear();

var nodes = (IEnumerable<Node>)bin.Deserialize(fs);

foreach(var node in nodes) {
    graphControl.Nodes.Add(node);
}
```